# stlink-org / 1.6.1 / STM32F723 / Raspberry Pi4

Tags: stm32, raspberry-pi4, flashing

I have a problem with flashing proc using https://github.com/stlink-org.

- Using windows STM32-Utility all works fine on every programer.
- I also using debug which works correctly
- Tried on other version v1.6.1.8x or 1.5.1 - this same problem

My setup:

- Raspbbery Pi 4 with NOOBs
- STM32F723, also i tried on Nucleo programer and ST-LINK / V2
- stlink version - v1.6.1-201-g4bfaab0

At this moment I can erase memory, but that's all. When I tried to flash it crashes.

```
./st-flash write test.bin 0x8000000
------------------------------------
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Flash page at addr: 0x08011480 erased
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Flash page at addr: 0x08011500 erased
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Flash page at addr: 0x08011580 erased
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Flash page at addr: 0x08011600 erased
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Flash page at addr: 0x08011680 erased
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Flash page at addr: 0x08011700 erased
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Finished erasing 559 pages of 128 (0x80) bytes
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Starting Flash write for L0
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Starting Half page flash write for STM32L core id
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO flash_loader.c: Successfully loaded flash loader in sram
2021-02-05T10:26:04 INFO common.c: Go to Thumb mode
2021-02-05T10:26:05 ERROR flash_loader.c: Flash loader run error (R2 0xF1000003 R15 0xF1000003 DHCSR 0x01080001 DFSR 0x0000000B)
2021-02-05T10:26:05 WARN common.c: l1_stlink_flash_loader_run(0x8000000) failed! == -1
2021-02-05T10:26:05 WARN common.c: 
write_half_pages failed == -1
^C[!] send_recv send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY
[!] send_recv STLINK_DEBUG_READREG
2021-02-05T10:26:16 INFO common.c: Go to Thumb mode
[!] send_recv send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY
[!] send_recv STLINK_DEBUG_WRITEREG
[!] send_recv send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY
[!] send_recv STLINK_JTAG_WRITEDEBUG_32BIT
[!] send_recv send request failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY
[!] send_recv STLINK_JTAG_WRITEDEBUG_32BIT
```

lsusb

```
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 060: ID 0483:374f STMicroelectronics STLINK-V3
    Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

./st-info --probe

```
Found 1 stlink programmers
  version:    V3J7S1
  serial:     303034343030333033303339353130353334333933383338
  hla-serial: "\x30\x30\x34\x34\x30\x30\x33\x30\x33\x30\x33\x39\x35\x31\x30\x35\x33\x34\x33\x39\x33\x38\x33\x38"
  flash:      196608 (pagesize: 128)
  sram:       20480
  chipid:     0x0447
  descr:      L0xx Category 5
```

Comment: Got same kind of failure. Worst, maintainers of stlink-org/stlink **delete** the issue when you report it... See also https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink/issues/607
but they locked the issue ...